# Reducing Firestore Entity Write Ops

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a micro service that writes certain data to the cloud. The objects are fairly simple, but I recently made the switch from firebase to firestore.

As a result, any part of the object which was originally being stored as an array...

```
{
    "Name": "Bob Dylan",
    "Records": [ ... ],
    ...
}
```

...was changed into a Firestore Document with appropriate collections...

```
{
    "Name": "Bob Dylan",
    ...
}
-> sub collection
Records: [ ... ]
```

What used to be a simple, painless write op, is now running me over quota making me exceed my limits. **How can I reduce the number of *Cloud Firestore Entity Writes* being performed?**

For context, I write about ~2000 objects a day. This would be 2000 objects in firebase, but the write ops are reported as 0.02 million, so it's about a 10x increase. Is the calculation based on something else?

**Update:**

Documentation for what consists of a write op can be found [at this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class).

So how can I write an entire sub collection in one call?
I have wrapped everything in firestore `Batch()` objects so that I am sending 500 at a time, but it appears to make no difference.

Comment: The number of document writes should be very predictable. But indeed: if you choose to store the records as documents in a subcollection, then each record write will equal a document write. Batching writes will help for network traffic, but doesn't change the number of documents being written. Aside from such generic observations, it's hard to say what's causing the discrepancy between what you expect and the actuals without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I guess that means I'm basically left with no options. I think it is counter intuitive moving from firebase, since you could write a single object (arrays or not) whereas in firestore a collection will cost a single write for each document added to a subcollection

Comment: The link you added in your update refers to Cloud Storage btw. That's a different product than Cloud Firestore. The detailed pricing info for the latter can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing